# Command Line Arguments and Chars

Tags: c

What is the proper way to receive a command line argument from the user and compare it to a single char? For example if the user typed "Y" for yes run some function and "N" for no would run another function.

My main error is "comparison between ptr and integer" & "too few arguments to function call, expected 3 have 1"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void calculate();
void verify();

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if(argc < 2){
        printf("Please enter a mode of operation.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(argc > 2){
        printf("Too many arguments supplied. Please try again.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(strncmp(argv[1] == 'c') == 0)
        calculate();

    else if(strncmp(argv[1] == 'v') == 0)
        verify();

return 0;
}

void calculate(){
}

void verify(){
}
```

Comment: `strncmp(argv[1] == 'c') == 0` --> `strcmp(argv[1], "c") == 0`

Comment: `strncmp(argv[1] == 'c')` --> `strncmp(argv[1], "c",1)`

Comment: BTW, which part of the error message was unclear?

Comment: You can convert it to `strncmp(argv[1], "c") == 0` to compare the argument to the string `c`

Comment: if you don't care what the rest of the string is you could just do `if(*argv[1]=='c')`?

Comment: Thank you, I actually didnt realize I had the  ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `strncmp()` correctly. It should be:

```
strncmp(argv[1], "c", 1)
```

It takes 3 arguments: two strings and a limit. `'c'` is a `char`, not a string, string literals are put in double quotes.

You can also write simply:

```
if (argv[1][0] == 'c')
```

This just checks the first character, so the user can type `y` or `yes` and they'll match `y`. If you want to match the whole argument and require it be just a single character, you should use `strcmp()` rather than `strncmp()`:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "c") == 0)
```

Comment: @4386427 - that is true and arguably, that might be what OP intended.

Comment: @4386427 I thought he just wanted to check the first letter. So you can type y or yes

Comment: @4386427 I've added more to the answer that explains both ways.

Comment: @Barmar - Good answer - covers both the exact match and the "match first letter" case

Answer (score 0):

This

```
strncmp(argv[1] == 'c') == 0
```

just is incorrect syntax. For starters the function `strncmp` requires three arguments and it deals with strings while in the avove call of the function there is supplied only one argument of type `int`. because the wrong expression `argv[1] == 'c'` has type `int` and is equal to 0.

I can suggest the following solution

```
else if ( argc > 2 || strlen( argv[1] ) != 1 ){
    printf("Too many arguments supplied. Please try again.\n");
    return 0;
}
else if ( argv[1][0] == 'c' )
    calculateCRC();

else if ( argv[1][0] == 'v' )
    verifyCRC();
```